# "*value += how_much" vs "*value += *how_much" in rust?

Tags: pointers, rust, dereference

In the following rust code, why do both of the functions `mutate_value()` work with and without dereferencing the how_much param? Shouldn't this not work since I am adding a reference to the value?

```rust
fn mutate_value(value: &mut i32, how_much: &i32) {
    *value += how_much
}

// fn mutate_value(value: &mut i32, how_much: &i32) {
//    *value += *how_much
// }


fn main() {
    let mut value = 5;
    let how_much = 10;
    mutate_value(&mut value, &how_much);
    println!("value: {}", value);
}
```

Comment: @cafce25 idk if that's true, but it is unnecessary since there's impls for values and references for all the integers.

Comment: @drewtate well [deref coercion happens with this syntax sugar](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c61810ffd747a672acbac064cc6aaaf9) but you're right it's not the cause here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i32`, as well as the other number primitives, implements `AddAssign` for two different right-hand-side types.

- [`&i32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.AddAssign.html#impl-AddAssign%3C%26i32%3E-for-i32)
- [`i32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.AddAssign.html#impl-AddAssign%3Ci32%3E-for-i32)

Your two functions use each of these respectively. You can see it clearly when the `AddAssign` impls aren't the same. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2222545f0dc7473a4a5cc0e1f409c761)

```rs
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct A(i32);

impl AddAssign for A {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, other: A) {
        println!("By value");
        self.0 += other.0;
    }
}

impl AddAssign<&A> for A {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, other: &A) {
        println!("By reference");
        // The . operator dereferences
        self.0 += other.0;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A(4);
    let b = A(6);
    // By value
    a += b;
    let c = &b;
    // By reference
    a += c;
    dbg!(a);
}
```